# "Start may not be called on a task that has completed" exception on task that did not start

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, task, cancellationtokensource

I am working on a mobile application developed with Xamarin, and every now and then I am receiving reports in which the application crashes because of the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException Start may not be called on a task that has completed.

In order to be clear, this is more or less the structure of the function where this happens:

```
    CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;

    void Function(bool condition1, bool condition2)
    {
        if (tokenSource != null)
        {
            tokenSource.Cancel();
            tokenSource.Dispose();
            tokenSource = null;
        }

        Task completionTask = null;

        if (condition1)
        {
            tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            completionTask = new Task(async () =>
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    if (tokenSource != null && !tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        InvokeOnMainThread(Function2);
                    }
                }, tokenSource.Token);
        }

        if (condition2)
        {
            TaskFactory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                  ...
                }).ContinueWith(() =>
                {
                    if (completionTask != null)
                    {
                        completionTask.Start();
                    }
                });
        }
        else
        {
            if (completionTask != null)
            {
                completionTask.Start();
            }
        }
    }

    void Function2()
    {
        if (tokenSource != null)
        {
            tokenSource.Cancel();
            tokenSource.Dispose();
            tokenSource = null;
        }
    }
```

I cannot manage to reproduce the bug, and also I am not sure how is it possible that `completionTask` has been already started, as it can be started only once. Even if, for any reason,  `Function` is called in sequence, or by multiple threads, this shouldn't cause any issue, as `completionTask` is a local variable.

Any idea about what could be the cause?

Comment: There is a property or method on the task to check if it has finished. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: if both condition1 and condition2 are true, looks to me like you could try to start completionTask twice.

Comment: As an aside, the general consensus is that [task constructors shouldn't be used](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html).

Comment: @CallumLinington That is true, and I am aware of it. But here the problem is that I don't know how is it possible that the task was started twice.

Comment: @user6144226 If condition1 is true, then the completionTask is just created, not started. If it is true, then, irregardless of condition2, it will be started

Comment: I can't imagine that your implementation is solving the problem in the best way, it would be better if you could provide the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: @CallumLinington I can see your point, but I wanted to remove all the "unnecessary" parts from my code in order to focus on the exception. The fact that maybe the code is not well structured or not the best, it is another story.

Comment: Yeah and maybe solving that story properly will lead to a bug free solution. otherwise known as the XY solution

Comment: @CallumLinington I can see why you would think this is an XY problem, but I don't think it this way. In this case my question was not about solving a specific problem, but about how my code could have caused the exception. And I think I also understood why.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a race condition on the cancellationToken since it is scoped across multiple function calls.
As such you can try to start a task that is canceled by function2 or by another call to the same function.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a sequence of events that could cause such a problem?

Comment: I just run the function 10x times in a loop. Oddly enough I could not reproduce this on Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/2sstvm

Comment: @markusian I actually find it quite wierd you are not awaiting these tasks anywhere?

Comment: I don't think it's odd that you couldn't reproduce it, because I don't understand the task could be run before calling `.Start()`, even if `Function` is called several times. Regarding awaiting tasks... well, I don't need to await them :)

Comment: Since you do not wait for the calls to END, a second run of the same function MIGHT try to start a new Task - which could get cancelled using the same cancellation Token from the first(or any previous) run

Comment: Even if the new task could get cancelled using an older cancellation token (from a previous run), I'm not sure how this could cause the exception I am seeing

Comment: @markusian the docs on Start.Task sepcify exactly this.  You'd expect it to say cancled instead of completed. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270682%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Actually I think I may have misunderstood your words before. Anyway this kind of exception can happen also if cancellation token source gets cancelled before we start the task. When .Start() gets called we get the exception